# How to use GPG to pass along encrypted content and double encrypt

Tags: gnupg

Say I have a document. I want to encrypt it, then give it to my friend, and I don't want them to be able to decrypt it. I want them to encrypt it again using their GPG system. Then to decrypt it my friend has to first decrypt it, send it to me, and I decrypt it.

How do I do that roughly with the GPG CLI? I am confused because there are 3 interrelated elements.

```
gpg --encrypt --sign --armor -r person@email.com -r foo@bar.com name_of_file
```

- encrypt
- sign
- recipients

I amnot sure how they all relate or what they do exactly. Do I just encrypt it without signing and without recipients, pass it to my friend and they encrypt it without signing or adding recipients?

Comment: This looks  like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) for me. Could you please explain what security problem (X) you are trying to solve with this kind of procedure (Y)? Maybe your original problem X can be solved in an easier way or maybe your procedure Y does not even solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to encrypt something twice, you can just call gpg twice:

```
<  name_of_file gpg --encrypt -r lance@email.com | gpg --encrypt -r friend@email.com > double-encrypted.gpg.gpg
```

Please note that the approach of encrypting a file for someone that they need to give you back doesn't make much (any?) sense. They receive an encrypted file, just to send you a (half-)decrypted copy (of something you already have), and in the end you need to send them the plaintext file anyway.

If what you want to do is to ensure that they need to contact you before decrypting it, you could give them a symmetrically encrypted file rather than one encrypted with *your* gpg key:

```
<  name_of_file gpg --cipher-algo aes --symmetric | gpg --encrypt -r friend@email.com > double-encrypted.gpg.gpg
```

This way you conceal the secret password (randomly generated, etc.) until when they need to decrypt it, and there's no need to send you back the file you already had.

I am skipping the signing part since you don't specify that you actually need signing, and you probably don't need it. I agree with Steffen Ullrich that it would be preferable that you stated you actual goal, rather than the way you wanted to solve it. Specifically, please note that this double-encryption doesn't preclude them from keeping a copy of the plaintext file and use it later on without your knowledge.